# Find specific user name of returning user using local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to detect new visitor on my page, ask for his name using prompt and store it on local storage. 
If he is a return user, show his name on the page using 'querySelector'.

I started from checking if it's a new user or not, but I got stuck.

```
var localStorage = window.localStorage;
    if(localStorage.getItem("reutrn_user")) {

      //

    } else {
        var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
        localStorage.setItem('username', name);
    }
```

Any idea how to get the username and show it in case he is a return user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `getItem` and `setItem` have different keys.

In your example, one key is `reutrn_user` and the other `username`.

---

```
var localStorage = window.localStorage;

if(localStorage.getItem("username")) {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("username"))
} else {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
    localStorage.setItem('username', name);
}
```